Evaluating $y^3+y^2+1$, where real $y$ satisfies $y^5+y-1=0$. Is there an exact answer?
Screenshot of the original problem:

To translated from Thai to English as I could
If $y$ is a real number that satifies
$$y^{5} + y - 1 = 0$$
then find $y^{3} + y^{2} +1 $
I tried to solve it by substitution but still can't solve this problem.
Is there an exact answer to this problem? and can anybody suggest some method please?
Sorry for my English. if there is a mistake.

According to Wolfram alpha there is an exact answer.

See this Stack Exchange Question

@vallev Can you share some trick how to factor polynomial equation faster please ? I guess factoring $ y^5 + y -1 = 0 $  is a kind of time-spending a lot

@PeanutSnack I used Approach0 search engine and found this post which discussed the factoring.

Not that neat but here is a way
We have $ y^5+y-1=0$ and $y^3+y^2+1=a$
$$y^5+y-1=0\\y^5+y^4-y^2-y^4-y^3+y+y^3+y^2-1=0\\y^2(y^3+y^2-1)-y^4-y^3+y+1(y^3+y^2-1)=0\\y^2(y^3+y^2-1)-(y^4+y^3-y)+(y^3+y^2-1)=0\\\\
(y^2-y+1)(y^3+y^2-1)=0$$
Adding and subtracting $1$ inside the second parenthesis we get
$$(y^2-y+1)(y^3+y^2+1-1-1)=0\\(y^2-y+1)(a-2)=0$$
So $a=2$
